# Vertically aligning Flexbox items, without causing Phantom Whitespace between items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem I'm facing here is that when using Flexbox's "`flex-wrap: wrap`", it seems to cause extra white space beneath the `div`.

My setup is like this (class names to clarify the use of the div):

```
<div class="viewheight-background">

    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="vertically-centered-text"></div>

</div>
```

My css is pretty straight forward:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.viewheight-background {
    min-height: 100%; /* To ensure a section of 100% screen height, could be done with 'vh' */
    background-size: cover;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.vertically-centered-text {
    align-self: center;
}
```

The vertically-centered-text is inside a div because I am dealing with a main heading and some subtext.

If I take away "`align-self: center`", the flex-items wrap just fine except for one thing. There seems to be some kind of phantom white-space which I can't identify. This causes "`align-self: center`" to be lower than the center of the `div` it should be centered in.

Any ideas?

(If I'm being too vague, please let me know and i'll clarify)

EDIT:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Murkrage/p16a2641/) for reference. Forgot to add `html, body {height: 100%;}`

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this error in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/cngf6rzh/1/) unless i'm missing the point?

Comment: @jbutler483 added fiddle for reference. Forgot to add a style

Comment: Please see my answer which (should) solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a decent solution.

It appears that:

***float, clear and vertical-align have no effect on a flex item.***

So I Found out the issue was with with your:

```
align-self: center;
```

on your second flex item.

So your css should be edited to:

```
.vertically-centered-text {
    /*align-self: center;*/
    background-color:blue;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As shown in this [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/p16a2641/1/) or run this snippet (in full page view):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.viewheight-background {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* To ensure a section of 100% screen height, could be done with 'vh' */
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vertically-centered-text {
  /*align-self: center;*/
  background-color: blue;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewheight-background">
  <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
  <div class="vertically-centered-text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But "align-self: center" is a flex property. It's used to align flex items within the flex container differently on the cross axis (which in my case is vertically). You have indeed centered the text inside the centered-text div, however I want the div to be centered inside the space that is left (so between the header and the bottom of the page).

Which works fine, but as you can see the header is left with a tremendous amount of whitespace (See the excess red on both our fiddles)

Comment: Quick edit to my comment: The "div.vertically-centered-text" has to be vertically centered within the "div.viewheight-background". I am almost certain this has something to do with "flex-wrap: wrap" being a pain in the ass.

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/p16a2641/2/) is what you want? (i placed the header outside of the vh). This is where the red (header) only uses the space it requires, while the blue (subtext) uses the rest and is displayed to the center.

Comment: Not exactly. The vh is there so that the background stretches all the way from the top to the bottom (vh is only the first part of this particular page). So the header has to be over the vh background as well. This may be done with negative margins, but then I'd need to use fixed heights which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: then how about setting a max-height: on your vertically centered text? Other than that, without the *full* markup, it's almost impossible to advise/see where the problem is currently.